# Special characters after syntax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, razor-2

I would like to know how to and is it posible to add special charaters after Razor syntax.

Example:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Text)()
```

The problem is with `()` at the end. I'd like to add it just after generated content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to the `<text></text>` markup, you can simply wrap your Html.Raw statement in parenthesis.  Example:

`@(Html.Raw(Model.Text))()`

This will prevent razor from trying to parse the extra set of parenthesis as they help razor determine when to stop parsing the markup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.Text)<text>()</text>
```

`<text></text>` is special razor markup, not to be confused with actual HTML.

> The `<text>` tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the `<text>` block as content, and to not render the containing `<text>` tag element (meaning only the inner contents of the `<text>` element will be rendered – the tag itself will not).  This makes it convenient when you want to render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML element.

Quoted from [ASP.NET MVC 3: Razor’s @: and `<text>` syntax](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/15/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax.aspx).